# Php can't write anything

Tags: linux, centos, php, chmod, chown

Just moved my websites to my first vps (centos 7). So i'm very new to linux. Now I have a problem: php cant write anything. Can't make dirs, files, edit them. Php runs as "apache" Things I tried:

- Chmod all dirs and files to 777
- Chown all dirs and files to "apache"
- Chown all dirs and files to "nobody"

Its simply wants to edit with file_put_contents(req.log, $content).

How can I fix it?

Edit:
**Ls -l:**

```
root@vps314463 data]# ls -l
total 120
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache  4096 Sep  8 11:12 EMAIL
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 30357 Sep  8 10:49 login.log
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache   510 Sep  8 10:49 loginfail.log
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 73268 Sep  8 10:49 req.log
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache   837 Sep  8 10:49 users copy 3.db
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache   994 Sep  8 10:49 users.db
```

Edit: 
Tried the answer of Kostas
I chmoded and chowned public_html/data. Then opened test.php in public_html in webbrowser with the following code:

```
<?php
mkdir("data/testdir")
?>
```

*Nothing happened and this error occurred:*

```
[Thu Sep 08 22:39:20.138500 2016] [:error] [pid 24286] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:47632] PHP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/example.com/public_html/usertest.php on line 3
```

Comment: Your question lack sufficient information to answer it. You should [edit] it to include relevant information such as the output of `ls -l` for the directories that you want PHP to be able to write to and the user/UID that PHP runs as. See [ask].

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thx, did it.

Comment: Do a `ls -ld` too. And `pwd` (both while in `data` directory)

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory / file inside a directory apache user should have write permissions to the parent directory.

```
chown apache.apache /path/to/data
```

and then

```
chmod 755 /path/to/data
```

Comment: Did'nt work, gave same error. See edit with more info.